# Video poster reset when mouseleave the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey everyone I'm working on a preview event when you hover over a div. However when the user mouseleave I want the HTML poster element to reset.

**Updated** [LINK](http://viscomcapstone.com/)

**HTML**

```
    <div class="story-panel-wrapper" id="">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col l7  m6 s12">
       <div class="stories">
        <span class="story-description">Hello World</span>
                    <div class="video">

            <div class="videoSlate">
                <div class="video-container">
                <video class="thevideo" width="978" poster="img/emily-poster.jpg" loop>
                  <source src="videos/emily.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col l5 m6 s12 ">
                    <div class="story-panel-container">
                    <div class="story-panel-content">
                    <h3 class="custom-red-text-margin">Emily: The Host of Designated Places</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce non dictum metus. Proin lacus leo, facilisis sed tincidunt placerat, aliquam sit amet massa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pretium, tortor a suscipit volutpat, metus libero finibus velit, quis pulvinar dolor lorem quis nibh. 
                    </p>


                </div>
 </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

**JQuery**
The JQuery so far is calling the video element when you hover over the class .story-panel-wrapper

```
var figure = $(".story-panel-wrapper").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );

function hoverVideo(e) {  
$('video', this).get(0).play(); 
};

function hideVideo(e) {
$('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want the HTML poster element to reset"? Return to the poster on video pause, you mean?

Comment: Your `LINK` doesn't link to anywhere.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the movie to stop and the poster to display when the mouse moves outside your div, just make this change:

```
function hideVideo(e) {
    // $('video', this).get(0).pause();        
    $('video', this).get(0).load(); 
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/dokaju/2/

To fade out the video and show the poster:

```
function hideVideo(e) {
    $video = $('video', this).get(0);
    $video.pause(); 

    $($video).fadeTo(200, 0.1, function() {
       $video.load();
       $($video).fadeTo(50, 1.0);
    });
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/mifadisuqi/2/

Comment: Hello, were you able to try this demo and verify it does what you want?

Comment: Is there a way to make it fadeIn or fadeTo the poster?

Comment: Yes, by using the fadeTo() method. Please see my updated answer. If I've answered your original question as asked, kindly accept my answer. You can always ask additional questions as you need customization :)

Comment: Thank you! You have been a great help!